# join strings within a list of lists by 4

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, loops, character

**Background**

I have a list of lists as seen below

```
l = [['NAME',':', 'Mickey', 'Mouse', 'was', 'here', 'and', 'Micky', 'mouse', 'went', 'out'], 
['Donal', 'duck', 'was','Date', 'of', 'Service',  'for',  'Donald', 'D', 'Duck', 'was', 'yesterday'], 
['I', 'like','Pluto', 'the', 'carton','Dog', 'bc','he', 'is','fun']]
```

**Goal**

Join `l` by every 4 elements (when possible)

**Problem**

But sometimes 4 elements won't cleanly join as 4 as seen in my desired output

**Desired Output**

```
desired_l = [['NAME : Mickey Mouse', 'was here and Micky', 'mouse went out'], 
    ['Donal duck was Date', 'of Service for Donald', 'D Duck was yesterday'], 
    ['I like Pluto the', 'carton Dog bc he', 'is fun']]
```

**Question**

How do I achive  `desired_l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) has some nifty functions, one of which can do this to do just this.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

[[' '.join(filter(None, x)) for x in list(grouper(sentence, 4, fillvalue=''))] for sentence in l]
```

Result:

```
[['NAME : Mickey Mouse', 'was here and Micky', 'mouse went out'],
['Donal duck was Date', 'of Service for Donald', 'D Duck was yesterday'],
['I like Pluto the', 'carton Dog bc he', 'is fun']]
```